# Java to PHP - function for X509EncodedKeySpec

Tags: java, php, rsa, x509, phpseclib

I have Java sample code for RSA encryption using public key which is in base64 format. Now I want to convert same thing in PHP. I tried to convert but some class are confusing me.This is java sample code.

```
public static String encrypt(String msg, String fileName) throws Exception {
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        RSAPublicKey cryptPublicKey = readPublicKeyFromFile(fileName);
        System.out.println("public "+cryptPublicKey);
        cipher.init(1, cryptPublicKey);
        String tempStr = msg;
        int modulus = tempStr.length() / 8;
        if (modulus != 0) {
            for (int i = modulus; i < 8; i++)
                tempStr = tempStr + " ";
        }
        byte plainData[] = tempStr.getBytes();
        byte binaryCryptData[] = cipher.doFinal(plainData);
        BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
        String encData = encoder.encode(binaryCryptData);
        msg = encData;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
    return msg;
}

private static RSAPublicKey readPublicKeyFromFile(String fileName) throws Exception {
    RSAPublicKey cryptPublicKey = null;
    try {
        KeyFactory keyFac = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        byte cryptKey[] = new byte[fis.available()];
        fis.read(cryptKey);
        fis.close();
        cryptKey = (new BASE64Decoder()).decodeBuffer(new String(cryptKey));
        X509EncodedKeySpec encodedKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(cryptKey);
        cryptPublicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyFac.translateKey(keyFac.generatePublic(encodedKeySpec));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
    return cryptPublicKey;
}
```

Now this is what I have tried to achieve samething in PHP:

```
$keyData =base64_decode(file_get_contents($configValues['metPubKey']));

print_r($keyData);
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();

try{
    $rsa->loadKey($keyData); // public key
    $encryptedToken = base64_encode($rsa->encrypt($token));
}catch(Exception $e){
    die;
}
```

In Java code there is `X509EncodedKeySpec` class in `readPublicKeyFromFile` function, which returns public key.I'm not sure what should I use in PHP. And also looks like php script not matching with Java code. Any help on this?

Comment: phpseclib uses OAEP padding by default - Java is probably using PKCS1 padding. So you'll probably need to do `$rsa->setSignatureMode(CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PKCS1)`. But even if you do that I wouldn't expect either to match, anyway, because both types of padding are randomized. ie. even in Java if you encrypt the same string multiple times you'll get different ciphertext's each time. The true test is to try to decrypt what you encrypt in one language with another language.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. `$rsa->setSignatureMode(CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PKCS1)` is needed for encryption? `$rsa->setPublicKeyFormat()` is used to define key format while encryption. correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Do you have any idea about equivalent methods for `javax.crypto.Cipher` class in PHP? `Crypt_RSA` is fine? I'm confused because we can use `mcrypt_encrypt` or `openssl_public_encrypt` etc.

Comment: `Crypt_RSA` should be fine. `mcrypt_encrypt` only works for symmetric ciphers (AES, RC4, etc). `openssl_public_encrypt` should work, too, but that one, arguably, could require more "finagling". Also, `$rsa->setPublicKeyFormat()` is mainly used when creating (or converting) keys. If all you're doing is encryption / decryption you shouldn't need to call that.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this. I have a similar situation in which I have to encrypt data in PHP and the decrypt in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this following code in PHP, it's worked for me.

```
use phpseclib\Crypt\RSA;

        $key = base64_decode(file_get_contents('PATH_TO_PUBLIC_FILE'));
        $rsa = new RSA();
        $rsa->setEncryptionMode(RSA::ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);
        $rsa->loadKey($key);
        $rsa->setPublicKey($key);
        $cipher = 'xxxx';
        $data = $this->hex2bin($cipher);
        $plaintext = $rsa->decrypt($data);
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($plaintext);
        echo '</pre>';die;
```

hex to byte:

```
public function hex2bin($hexdata) {
    $bindata = "";

    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($hexdata); $i += 2) { $bindata .= chr(hexdec(substr($hexdata, $i, 2))); } return $bindata;
}
```